# MongoDB, Multiple count (with $exists)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have these 3 requests:

```js
db.mycollection.count({requestA:{$exists:true}})
db.mycollection.count({requestB:{$exists:true}})
db.mycollection.count({requestC:{$exists:true}})
```

I'd like to make only one request...
So i tried the following:

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        '_id' : { user_id: '$user_id'},
        requestA_count: { $sum: {
            $cond: [ {requestA:{'$exists':true}}, 1, 0 ]
        } },
        requestB_count: { $sum: {
            $cond: [ {requestB:{'$exists':true}}, 1, 0 ]
        } },
        requestC_count: { $sum: {
            $cond: [ {requestC:{'$exists':true}}, 1, 0 ]
        } },
    } },
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        user_id: '$_id.user_id',
        requestA_count: 1,
        requestB_count: 1,
        requestC_count: 1
    } }
] );
```

But i got the error:

```js
"errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$exists'",
```

I guess that we cannot use $exists with $project.

Any tips about a good approach ? Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You had the right basic idea but [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is a query condition so is only valid witin a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/). What you want is the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator to essentially do the same thing:

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate( [
    { "$group": {
        "_id" : { "user_id": "$user_id" },
        "requestA_count": { "$sum": {
            "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": ["$requestA", false] }, 1, 0 ]
        } },
        "requestB_count": { "$sum": {
            "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": ["$requestB", false] }, 1, 0 ]
        } },
        "requestC_count": { "$sum": {
            "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": ["$requestC", false] }, 1, 0 ]
        } },
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "user_id": "$_id.user_id",
        "requestA_count": 1,
        "requestB_count": 1,
        "requestC_count": 1
    } }
] );
```

So the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) either returns the present value of the field if it exists or the "right side" argument is returned if it does not. The returned value other than `false` is intrepreted as being `true` ( unless of course the value is actually false ).

Essentially this gives you the same functionality of logically testing for the existence of a property in the document.

Comment: Thank you Neil for the explanation !

Comment: Actually Neil, requestA_count, requestB_count, requestC_count have always the same value... :/ ! I mean, if requestA_count = 9 then requestB_count and requestC_count = 9

Comment: @JohnSmith can you edit your question to show some data with different fields present. For me this works. If the field does not exist the the value passed to sum is 0.

Comment: @JohnSmith Sorry. Silly typo. All the fields need to be prefixed with `$` as I have done in the edit. That means they use the field value in a variable as was intended. The plain strings would compare to evaluate `false`. Should work for you now.

Comment: My bad, i gave you a wrong example ! It's working fine now ! I just need to sort it ! :). Thanks a lot